# Need help dry running, dont know how output is the way it is

Tags: c++

I'm having difficulty dry running this code. I can understand clearly whats going on till:

Line 8

Line 8

Line 9

Line 7

Line 8

Line 1

but after this things get muddy. Can someone explain just a little bit please? How are there three Line 7s after the above? Shouldn't there be two?

Sorry its a bit long but I'm at a loss to see how I'm not getting it right.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Square {
    friend Square operator -(Square sq1, Square sq2);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Square & s);
private:
int side;
public:
Square(int);
        Square(Square &);
        Square operator+(Square);
        Square operator/(Square);
        Square operator ++(int);
        Square operator--();
        int getSide();
int getArea();
};

Square::Square(int _side){
   cout<<"Line 8"<<endl;                   
side = _side;
}
Square::Square(Square & s){
   cout<<"Line 7"<<endl;
side = s.side;
}

Square Square :: operator +(Square sq){
   Square squareTemp(0);
squareTemp.side = side + sq.side/sq.side - 1;
cout<<"Line 1"<<endl;
return squareTemp-sq-sq;
}
Square Square :: operator /(Square sq){
    Square squareTemp(0);
squareTemp.side = side - 1;
cout<<"Line 2"<<endl;
return --squareTemp;
}

Square Square :: operator ++(int i){
    Square squareTemp(0);
squareTemp.side = side + 2;
cout<<"Line 3"<<endl;
return squareTemp;
}
Square Square :: operator --(){
    Square squareTemp(0);
squareTemp.side = (squareTemp.side++) +side + 1;
cout<<"Line 4"<<endl;
return squareTemp;
}

int Square :: getSide(){
    cout<<"***If this is the last line of output then it is Wrong Result"<<endl;
return side;
}

int Square :: getArea(){
    cout<<"Line 5"<<endl;
side++;
return side * side;
    cout<<"Line 21"<<endl;
}

Square operator-(Square sq1, Square sq2){
    Square squareTemp(0);
squareTemp.side = sq1.side + sq2.side;
cout<<"Line 6"<<endl;
return squareTemp;
}

ostream&operator<<(ostream& out, Square & s){
    out<<"s.side"<<endl;
return out;
}


int main(){
Square s1(3);
Square s2(4);
cout<<"Line 9"<<endl;

Square s = s1 + s2;
cout<<"Side of s:"<<s.getSide() <<endl;
cout<<"Area of s:"<<s.getArea() <<endl;
cout<<s1<<endl;
cout<<s2<<endl;
cout<<s.getSide()<<endl;
system("PAUSE");
}
```

**Output:**

Line 8

Line 8

Line 9

Line 7

Line 8

Line 1

Line 7

Line 7

Line 7

Line 8

Line 6

Line 7

Line 8

Line 6

Line 7

***If this is the last line of output then it is Wrong Result

Side of s:11

Line 5

Area of s:144

s.side

s.side

***If this is the last line of output then it is Wrong Result

12

Comment: So how many copies do you think `squareTemp-sq-sq;` creates ? Look at the *parameters* of the operator. `(Square sq1, Square sq2)`

Comment: Also, you can pretty quickly determine where these sorts of things happen by stepping through your program line by line in a debugger.  Whenever you don't understand why code is doing what it is doing, the debugger will show you and may even teach you some pretty cool/useful things in the process.  Most good programmers know most of what they know by their experience with real code in debuggers, not from what they did in school.  Might as well start now. :)

Comment: What I'm thinking is that - creates sq1 sq2 using the copy constructor and then creates squareTemp using the parametrized constructor. Line 6 is printed and squareTemp is returned. Then - is called again and sq1 and sq2 are created again to compute the statement you are referring to.

Comment: @dodexahedron Thanks for the tip. I don't know how exactly debugging is done right now so I guess I'll have to follow some tutorial later to understand it.

Comment: This would be much easier to follow if you wrote the name of the funciton it was in instead of "Line N"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you're getting confused on is bit from `operator+`.

```
cout<<"Line 1"<<endl;
return squareTemp - sq - sq;
```

The sequence of steps is

1. evaluate `squareTemp - sq`, which matches `Square::operator-(Square sq1, Square sq2)`
2. copy-construct argument `sq1` from `squareTemp` - output "Line 7"
3. copy-construct argument `sq2` from `sq` - output "Line 7"
4. Output "Line 7" (I will explain this in a moment)
5. int-construct `squareTemp` in `operator-` - output "Line 8"
6. `operator-` outputs "Line 6"
7. Copy-construct the return value of `operator-` from `squareTemp - output "Line 7"
8. Now we have the second part of `(squareTemp-sq) - sq` which is `Square::operator-(Square sq1, Square sq2)`

   1. The return value is used as `sq1` - in theory another copy could be done, but the compiler elides this.
   2. The object created in step 4 is `sq2` here
9. (Repeat steps 5,6,7 to output "Line 8" "Line 6" "Line 7"

The reason that the step 4 is allowed to be created there even though it isn't used until step 8, is because there is no sequence point in the expression:

```
Square::operator-( Square::operator-(squareTemp, sq), sq )
```

The compiler must evaluate `squareTemp` and the first `sq` before calling the inner `operator-`. However, it is free to evaluate the second `sq` at any point before the call to the second `operator-`.